# War deploy multiple class instance created when a job is executed

Tags: java, spring, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I have an web application which use quartz to execute planned jobs. I'm doing the development in embedded eclipse tomcat where when a job has to be executed it's executed just one time, but when I create an simple war and deployed in jboss the trigger execution has an strange behavior, the class called (job) is executed twice at same time, I checked the log and the execution call it's made just once

```
2014-12-30 11:25:30,003 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG [org.quartz.core.JobRunShell] - Calling execute on job DEFAULT.JobListener
```

But the method is executed twice

```
2014-12-30 11:25:30,003 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG [com.xxx.imides.batch.exec.JobListener] - executeInternal 
2014-12-30 11:25:30,003 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG [com.indra.xxx.batch.exec.JobListener] - executeInternal 
 2014-12-30 11:25:30,004 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG [com.indra.xxx.batch.exec.JobListener] - hashCode 20730000
2014-12-30 11:25:30,004 [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0_Worker-1] DEBUG [com.indra.xxx.batch.exec.JobListener] - hashCode 20730000
```

After a lot of test and research i'm completely lost, i don't now where and what to look. Any idea?

This is the application configuration:

POM.xml

```
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>

                <!-- Quartz framework -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

quartz-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="jobListener" class="com.xxx.imides.batch.exec.JobListener"></bean>

    <!-- Quartz Job -->
    <bean name="JobListener" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.xxx.imides.batch.exec.JobListener"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
    <bean id="cronTriggerJobListener" 
                class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean" scope="singleton" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobListener" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerJobListener" />
            </list>
        </property>
           <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

web.xml - I have this between everything

```
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener> 
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
 </listener>
```

JobListener.java

```
public class JobListener extends QuartzJobBean{
....
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("executeInternal ");
            logger.debug("jobRunTime " + context.getJobRunTime());
            logger.debug("toString " + context.getJobDetail().toString());
            logger.debug("hashCode " + context.getJobInstance().hashCode());

        }  
        pickUpChanges();

    }
}
```

Jboss

> JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 
>   6.3.0.GA

Comment: Try remove `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` declaration in your `web.xml`.

Comment: If I do this the applications just doesn't work at all.